# I want to handle textfield in Customtableview. and my tableview has 2 section. swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I want to get text of selected cell textfield and i am using customtableview which has 2 sections and i want data from first section only.my data is being saved it's working now problem is when i change my category to second and select some items and after  i came back to first one data in the textfield are gone because of changing category.so to handle that i created **Dictionary **.

```
var textfieldValue = [Int:[Int:String]]()
```

But this is not working it always give me found nil exception.
Below is my code. If you find my question is unclear please ask me.

**CellforrowAt**

```
if indexPath.section == 0 && food.count != 0
            {
                print(indexPath.section)

            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foodnamecell", for: indexPath) as! FoodnameTableCell
               if SelectedFoodImages.count != 0
               {
                cell2.foodImagedb.image = imagereturn(urrl: SelectedFoodImages[indexPath.row])
                }
                cell2.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
                cell2.foodnamelbl.textColor = UIColor.black
                print(food[indexPath.row])
                cell2.foodnamelbl.text = food[indexPath.row]
                cell2.foodUnitlbl.text = foodunitlbl[indexPath.row]
                cell2.foodcallbl.text = Selectedfoodcal[indexPath.row]

                cell2.qty.delegate = self
                cell2.qty.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

                cell2.qty.tag = indexPath.row
                if indexSave[catid]![indexPath.row] == true
                {
                    cell2.accessoryType = .checkmark

                }
                else
                {
                    cell2.accessoryType = .none
                }
                if textfieldValue[catid]?[indexPath.row] != nil

                {
                    print(textfieldValue[catid]?[indexPath.row] as Any)

                cell2.qty.text = textfieldValue[catid]?[indexPath.row]

                }
                else
                {
                    print(textfieldValue[catid]?[indexPath.row] as Any)
                    cell2.qty.text = ""
                }

                print(cell2.qty.tag)
                cell2.qty.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                cell = cell2
            }
```

**textfieldshouldbeginEditing**

```
var temp1 = [Int:String]()
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {



        temp1[textField.tag] = textField.text

        textfieldValue[catid] = temp1
       // print(textfieldValue)
        return true
    }
```

**textfield end editing**

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(textfieldValue)
        print(indexSave)


                let index = NSIndexPath(row: textField.tag,section:0)
                let cell = foodtableview.cellForRow(at:index as IndexPath) as! FoodnameTableCell

                limit = limit + (Int(cell.qty.text!))! * (Int(cell.foodcallbl.text!))!
                if limit >= (Int(calorieslbl.text!))!
                {
                    setalertt(title: "Error", message: "Calories Limit Reached")
                }

//        for i in 0...(textfieldValue[catid]?.count)! - 1
//        {
//            print(i)
//            
//            print(textfieldValue[catid]![textField.tag]! as Any)
//            limit = limit + Int(textfieldValue[catid]![textField.tag]!)!
//        }
        print(limit)
    }
```

** text field did change this is a selector which is in cellforrowat **

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

      //  var temp = [Int:String]()
        //temp[textField.tag] = textField.text

        textfieldValue[catid]?[textField.tag] = textField.text
        //print(textfieldValue)
//        let a = textField.text
//        print(a!)
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear in specifying the problem. Please specify clearly what you are trying to achieve and where the problem lies. It would also help if you were to mention the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour of the posted code.

Comment: @Malik now check please i hope it's clear now.

Comment: plz . . state , which line causes exception . it will ease debugging .

Comment: '        textfieldValue[catid]?[textField.tag] = textField.text
' where ever this line is used

Comment: do u want to access your text field and pass the textfield text?

Comment: i want to save that textfield text and send to database  @Maddy

Comment: where is catid being set?

Comment: pickerview didselectrow @Malik

Comment: before you use `textfieldValue[catid]?[textField.tag] = textField.text`, try printing the values of all the variables involved in this line and share the output

Comment: printing correct values catid = 0 , textfield.tag = 0 because i am selecting first cell and textfield.text also @Malik

Comment: can you post the error that is being displayed in the console?

Comment: bro error is gone now but when i enter second value mean second textfield first value is being replaced by this ""  now i selected two cell there value are entered like this ' [0: [2: "3", 1: "32"]]' now i changed my category and selected on cell now one value is inserted automatically [0: [2: "3", 1: "32"], 1: [2: "2", 1: "32"]]  this value is inserted automaticaly **2: "2"** @Malik

Comment: Based on your code, the output makes sense. You are changing the value of textfieldValue on textFieldDidChange. This means that on every character edit, your Dictionary would and should be updating. You haven't placed any checks to discard certain entries and I can't really suggest a check until I fully understand what it is you are trying to achieve

Comment: can we talk on skype i will share my screen so you can understand it better @Malik

Comment: @sudipto.bd help please?

Comment: if catid , textField.tag has an individual value  , then there is a chance that UITextField in the storyboard is not connected to your outlet textField , that you are working with , and check textField.delegate = self or not . plz confirm that

Comment: yes delegate is set to self and it's properly connected no issue there @sudipto.bd